# android AsyncTask with activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, activity-lifecycle

Am using `AsyncTask` in order to download images within my activity

the flow goes like this:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
        \\begin animation
}

protected IUpiResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
         \\ download the image
}

protected void onPostExecute(IUpiResponse upiResponse) {
         \\stop the animation
}
```

till here everything fine, the problem start if i go to background while the asynctask is working 
sometimes I get an exception nullpointer in the animation stops, because the views no longer valid (i guess),

I can check before the stop animation if the activity is in foreground but i prefer to avoid this approach, what else i can do ?

Comment: Did you try it surrund with `try {} catch{}` ?

Comment: i agree i can catch this exception, but i prefer to avoid this kind of trick

Comment: are you switching to another activity when you come into the onPostExecute()??

Comment: In that case catch the exception and make print it so you know what is the issue, there you can see what you can make.

Comment: To little information to give an answer, but keep in mind that an `AsyncTask` does not run on UI thread, therefore you cannot access/update Views directly from the `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Narendra pal: am not switching any activity  AndyRes: am doing update from the pre and post Execute not in doinBackground

Comment: testing if the view is still visible before stopping an animation on it sound perfectly reasonable to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to avoid the `asyncTask` approach and to download the images in a simple thread, which also  saves them to persistence layer such as file system, and then sends an `Intent` ,

**Note:** if the activity in the background the `Intent` ( if you register and unregister your receiver in onResume and onPause as advised ) will not be received so to avoid such cases inside `onResume` you can check if there is update waiting for you

Comment: This is super cheat / workaround / fake solution.. ;(